# Parse data from multiple numbers in a list or slice - TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, list, api, range, slice

**The problem**

I am trying to get a list of statuses of all support tickets from freshdesk.

So far I have been able to request.get all the tickets but it comes out with too much information. So I am trying to only pull the "status" from the json data.

Here is what happens if I want to print just 1 ticket's information:

```
ticketresponse = requests.get(freshdeskticketsurl, auth = (freshdeskapi, freshdeskpassword))
ticket_json = ticketresponse.json()


ticket_str = json.dumps(ticket_json[0], indent=2)
print(ticket_str)
```

Response:

```
{
  "cc_emails": [],
  "fwd_emails": [],
  "reply_cc_emails": [],
  "ticket_cc_emails": [],
  "fr_escalated": false,
  "spam": false,
  "email_config_id": null,
  "group_id": 43000110950,
  "priority": 1,
  "requester_id": taking that out of this example,
  "responder_id": taking that out of this example,
  "source": 3,
  "company_id": taking that out of this example,
  "status": 5,
  "subject": "Receptiontv-min - can't use slide show in powerpoint",
  "association_type": null,
  "support_email": null,
  "to_emails": null,
  "product_id": null,
  "id": taking that out of this example,
  "type": "Trouble Ticket",
  "due_by": "2021-03-09T19:21:09Z",
  "fr_due_by": "2022-02-25T19:21:09Z",
  "is_escalated": false,
  "custom_fields": {},
  "created_at": "2021-03-02T19:21:09Z",
  "updated_at": "2021-03-02T19:21:16Z",
  "associated_tickets_count": null,
  "tags": []
}
```

**I ONLY want the "status"** section. I can do that with only 1 ticket by doing this:

```
ticketresponse = requests.get(freshdeskticketsurl, auth = (freshdeskapi, freshdeskpassword))
ticket_json = ticketresponse.json()


ticket_str = json.dumps(ticket_json[0]['status'], indent=2)
print(ticket_str)
```

Response:

```
5
```

However, where I am having trouble is trying to print out the status for all the tickets at once. I can print out all the tickets at once by using `ticket_str = json.dumps(ticket_json, indent=2) print(ticket_str)`

However if I try any of the following lines of code to try and get all the status, it gives me the same error:

`ticket_str = json.dumps(ticket_json['status'], indent=2)`

Response
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

`ticketslice = slice(0,20) ticket_str = json.dumps(ticket_json[ticketslice]['status'], indent=2)`

Response
`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

If anyone has any ideas or has a different approach to the idea let me know.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Why you re trying to get the `ticket_str` variable at first with `ticket_str = json.dumps(ticket_json[0], indent=2)` end then with `ticket_str = json.dumps(ticket_json['status'], indent=2)` ?

Comment: `ticket_json` is a list - why do you try to use it as dictionary instead of iterating through it like this `for element in ticket_json: element["status"]`

Comment: I apologize, I am new to this. Those are two different examples of attempts I tried; if that makes any sense.

ticket_str = json.dumps(ticket_json[0], indent=2)  --- I was me trying to export out just 1 ticket from the api. This works completely

ticket_str = json.dumps(ticket_json['status'], indent=2) --- This was my trying to export out only the status of everyticket. Since `ticket_str = json.dumps(ticket_json, indent=2)` worked to give me all the tickets, I thought `ticket_str = json.dumps(ticket_json['status'], indent=2)` would give me all the status of every ticket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the statuses you need to loop on the response array, something like that:

```py
for i in range(len(ticket_json)):
    ticket_str = json.dumps(ticket_json[i], indent=2)
    print(ticket_str['status'])
```

Comment: I copied that code at first and got an error:

`print(ticket_str['status'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
`

So I switched it around and I think I got the responses I wanted:
```for i in range(len(ticket_json)):
    ticket_str = json.dumps(ticket_json[i]['status'], indent=2)
    print(ticket_str)```

I am going to mark this as the correct answer as this helped me to get to what I need. I don't know much about for loops but I am going to watch some videos on it now to help me understand how to use them better. 

I thank everyone for helping me out!!!